Why LowLevelMouseProc get negative values when moving the cursor quickly

I wrote a simple program to get the mouse position using win32api. But I found that sometimes negative values ​​appear. Why is that?

import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
import sys

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200

class POINT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_long), ("y", ctypes.c_long)]

class MSLLHOOKSTRUCT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("pt", POINT), ("mouseData", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD), ("flags", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD), ("time", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD), ("dwExtraInfo", ctypes.c_ulong)]

def showxy(x, y):
    print("x=%d y=%d" % (x, y), end="              \r")

def LowLevelMouseProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    if nCode == 0:
        if wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            msl = ctypes.cast(lParam, ctypes.POINTER(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)).contents
            x = msl.pt.x
            y = msl.pt.y
            showxy(x, y)
        elif wParam == 513:
            print("Left button pressed")
        elif wParam == 0x0204:
            print("Right button pressed")
    return user32.CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM(wParam), ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM(lParam))

def main():
    LRESULT = ctypes.c_long
    MYCFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(LRESULT, ctypes.wintypes.INT, ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM, ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM)
    CFIMCP = MYCFUNC(LowLevelMouseProc)
    hook_id = user32.SetWindowsHookExW(14, CFIMCP, None, 0)
    msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
    while user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
        user32.TranslateMessage(msg)
        user32.DispatchMessageW(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



I only use one monitor. Move the cursor to the screen coordinates and then quickly move it up and down to see negative values.

Why do you install a low-level mouse hook to monitor the current mouse position? What problem are you really trying to solve here?

@IInspectable I was studying win32api today, and then I found this glitch.

Didn't the hook process the message? Why is ncode equal to 0? See: If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message to the CallNextHookEx function without further processing and should return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.

The wParam and lParam parameters contain information about a mouse message if nCode =0. @Torrecto-MSFT

@kouhe3 Well that's weird. Have you tried in other IDE? I writed it in c++ and runned it in visual studio. Didn't get negative values. https://i.sstatic.net/OltXUno1.png

@Torrecto-MSFT https://gist.github.com/kouhe3/3efa62149c606359fe32b2a26bd8af7f  I tried C++, this is my code. and it works well in GetCursorPos.

@kouhe3 It also runs well. So I speculate that it is more related to python. No problem with win32 Api.
